# Convert Pandas Dataframes value in a loop

Tags: python, pandas

Want to convert a dataframe with `object` value in `n`, `y`, and `?` to `0`, `1`, and `0`

here's the `df.head()`:

```py
df.head()
party   infants water   budget  physician   salvador    religious   satellite   aid missile immigration synfuels    education   superfund   crime   duty_free_exports   eaa_rsa
0   republican  n   y   n   y   y   y   n   n   n   y   ?   y   y   y   n   y
1   republican  n   y   n   y   y   y   n   n   n   n   n   y   y   y   n   ?
2   democrat    ?   y   y   ?   y   y   n   n   n   n   y   n   y   y   n   n
3   democrat    n   y   y   n   ?   y   n   n   n   n   y   n   y   n   n   y
4   democrat    y   y   y   n   y   y   n   n   n   n   y   ?   y   y   y   y
```

I have tried to use a simple `for` loop:

```py
for names in df.columns.values:
    df.names.replace(('n', 'y'), (0, 1), inplace=True)
    df.names.replace('?', 0, inplace=True)
```

But it return me an `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'names'`

Please share me any idea to convert the `object` value into `int` value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use [`DataFrame.replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) without `inplace`:

```
df = df.replace(('n','?','y'), (0,0,1))
#alternative
df = df.replace({'n':0,'?':0,'y':1})
```

---

```
print (df)
        party  infants  water  budget  physician  salvador  religious  \
0  republican        0      1       0          1         1          1   
1  republican        0      1       0          1         1          1   
2    democrat        0      1       1          0         1          1   
3    democrat        0      1       1          0         0          1   
4    democrat        1      1       1          0         1          1   

   satellite  aid  missile  immigration  synfuels  education  superfund  \
0          0    0        0            1         0          1          1   
1          0    0        0            0         0          1          1   
2          0    0        0            0         1          0          1   
3          0    0        0            0         1          0          1   
4          0    0        0            0         1          0          1   

   crime  duty_free_exports  eaa_rsa  
0      1                  0        1  
1      1                  0        0  
2      1                  0        0  
3      0                  0        1  
4      1                  1        1
```

Generally `inplace` is not recommended - [link](https://www.dataschool.io/future-of-pandas/#inplace):

> The pandas core team discourages the use of the **inplace** parameter, and eventually it will be deprecated (which means "scheduled for removal from the library"). Here's why:
>
> **inplace** won't work within a method chain.
> The use of **inplace** often doesn't prevent copies from being created, contrary to what the name implies.
> Removing the **inplace** option would reduce the complexity of the pandas codebase.

In your code `names` is column name and you want replace values of this column only:

```
df.names.replace
```

And error mean there is no column `names`:

> AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'names'